# Django. How to store parent model fields from mixin in child model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

please I have an issue with model relationships in my Django project. For instance I have a model `Foo` which inherits from a model mixin `FooBarMixin` which is an abstract class and `Bar` which is a model but has a `OnetoOne` relationship with `Foo`. Basically this is the current implementation.

```
class Foo(FooBarMixin):
        pass

class FooBarMixin(model.Model):
    bar = model.OneToOneField(Bar, on_delete=CASCADE,             
                     related_name="tracked_%(class)s")
    class Meta:
         abstract = True

class Bar(model.Model):
     pass
```

Is it possible to store `Bar` data on the child model `Foo` without using a `OnetoOne` relationship ? and if so how do I go about it? Thank you

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Your mixin defines a one-to-one relationship with bar, so how can you expect to store the data without a relationship?

Comment: Why do you specify this `OneToOneField` then?

Comment: Sorry I meant I want the fields in `Bar` to be visible on the `Foo` table.

Comment: @Johnbosco: you could patch `__getattr__` for that.

Comment: It was specified because other models in the project are using the `mixin` as well

Comment: @ Willem Van Onsem Would the `__getattr__` be in the `FooBarMixin`?

Comment: @Johnbosco: you can patch it on whatever level you want. At the `FooBarMixin`, or at `Foo`, if you only want that behavior for `Foo`s.

Answer (score 1):

> Sorry I meant I want the fields in `Bar` to be visible on the `Foo` table.

Based on your comment you thus want to fetch fields of the `Bar` relation in `Foo` instances.

We could do that by patching the `__getattr__` function:

```
class Foo(FooBarMixin):

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        try:
            return super(Foo, self).__getattr__(name)
        except AttributeError:
            return getattr(self.bar, name)
```

So in case the attribute can *not* be fecthed from the `Foo` instance itself, we fallback on the corresponding `self.bar` object, and aim to obtain the attribute at that place.

Setting the attribute would require to override the `__setattr__` function in a similar way, although I would advice against that, since it will introduce all kinds of side-effects (saving the corresponding `.bar` object, etc.).

Comment: Thank you @Willem Van Onsem. I would like to reuse this on other models. Is there a way to do it in the `FooBarMixin` while also removing the `OnetoOne` relationship for `bar` currently in the `FooBarMixin`?

Comment: Well you can write the `bar` relation at another place (the subclasses of the  mixin), and thus patch the `__getattr__` of the mixin itself. But then you have to make sure that you somehow implement a `.bar` relation in the subclasses (not per se pointing to a `Bar` instance, but to some instance).